# NameError: name [nome] is not defined

Tags: python, syntax-error

Preciso fazer uma programação em Python para saber a porcentagem CG numa cadeia de DNA...

```
maior = 0
dnaMaior = ""
while True:
     dna = input("Digite uma sequencia de DNA: ")
     if dna == "Z" or dna == "z":
      break
     else:
        tam = len(dna)
        indice = 0
        while indice < len(dna):
            if dna == "C" or dna == "G":
                C = C + 1
                G = G + 1
            indice = indice+1
        percCG = ((C+G)*100)/len(dna)
        maior = percCG
        dnaMaior = dna
        print(dnaMaior)
```

Pois ocorre um erro de sintaxe. Por que ocorre esse erro, e como corrigi-lo?

> ```
> Digite uma sequencia de DNA: CCCCCCCGGGGGGGGAAAAAAAATTTT
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:/Users/13104855/Downloads/exerc_02T2.py", line 18, in <module>
>     percCG = ((C+G)*100)/len(dna)
> NameError: name 'C' is not defined
> ```

Answer (score 6):

Tem alguns problemas no seu código, mas este não é o foco da pergunta.

Este erro é por causa dessas linhas

```
C = C + 1
G = G + 1
```

Uma vez que C e G não foram declaradas, você não pode atribuir a elas o valor delas mesmas incrementadas de 1. Simplesmente declarar as variáveis antes de entrar no loop já resolve

```
maior = 0
dnaMaior = ""
while True:
     dna = raw_input("Digite uma sequencia de DNA: ")
     if dna == "Z" or dna == "z":
      break
     else:
        tam = len(dna)
        indice = 0
        C = 0
        G = 0
        while indice < len(dna):
            if dna == "C" or dna == "G":
                C = C + 1
                G = G + 1
            indice = indice+1
        percCG = ((C+G)*100)/len(dna)
        maior = percCG
        dnaMaior = dna
        print(dnaMaior)
```